# NUnit Assert that row has been added to database

Tags: c#, sql-server, nunit

Is it possible to use NUnit to assert that a new row has been added to a table in a database?
Eg, in the below update, how would you assert that a new row has been added?

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = 
    new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("ConnectionString");

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT Region (RegionID, RegionDescription) VALUES (5, 'NorthWestern')";
cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

sqlConnection1.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` returns the number of rows affected. so you can check for what it return

```
int ret =(int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command